# which function will be consider as view model in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

i am new in knockout js. so please see my below code and tell me which function will be consider as view model ?

there are two function one is `CartLine` and other one is Cart.............which function will be consider as view model ?

see this code `ko.applyBindings(new Cart());`

apply binding pointing Cart function.......so does it mean `cart()` will be consider as view model ? if yes then what we should `CartLine()` ? is it child or nested view model ?

looking for guidance. code taken from this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3bu6nybk/15/

```
var CartLine = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.products = ko.observableArray(_products);
          self.product = ko.observable(1);
          self.price = ko.observable(1);
          self.quantity = ko.observable(1);   
          self.product.subscribe(function(item){
              if(!item)
              { 
                 self.price(0);
                 self.quantity(0);
                 return;
              }
             self.price(item.price);
             self.quantity(item.quantity);
          });

          self.subtotal = ko.computed(function () {

              return self.price() * self.quantity();
          },self);
      };

      var Cart = function () {
          // Stores an array of lines, and from these, can work out the grandTotal
          var self = this;
          self.lines = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default
          self.formatCurrency = formatCurrency;

      };
```

Comment: Your view-model is the object you pass as an argument to the `applyBindings()` method.

Comment: @haim770 if see my posted code then u can see there are two functions called `CartLine  & Cart `. so my question is which function will be called as view model ? both will be considered as view model or the one which is pass a argument to `ko.applyBindings()`  function ?

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose all of your code in a variable like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    //your code here
}
```

then call your apply bindings like so:

```
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Everything will be in your viewmodel.

See this link for more info: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: u just do not understand my question. suppose i have many object literal like one `var viewModel = {
    //your code here
}`  then which one would be consider as view model ?

Comment: Whatever you 'applyBindings' to is your viewmodel. Viewmodel is a term that means the bridge between your model and your view (server and client).